# ERC20 token creation

Tags: tokens, erc-20

If I create an ERC20 token using a smart contract, how do I reference a contracts ethereum balance? Or do I just need to update some value like --> ethStore and then send transfers based on that value?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Veuillez fournir des informations complémentaires

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to version 0.5.0, the contract balance would be called via:
`this.balance`

This is now forbidden and an explicit conversion to address must be done:

`address(this).balance`

So just make sure which version of Solidity you are using.